# Вставка кода HTML прямо в Редактор текста Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Хочу прямо во время писания поста в Wordpress вставить html-код.
Вот такой кусок

```html
<div class="project">
  <a id="project_main_page" class="btn btn-project" href="#">Main</a>
  <a id="project_contact_page" class="btn btn-project" href="#">Contact</a>
  <a id="project_single_post" class="btn btn-project" href="#">Post</a>
  <a id="project_category" class="btn btn-project" href="#">Category</a>
  <iframe src="mysite.com/mypage"></iframe>
 </div>
```

Проблемма в том что редактор Wordpress, тот что встроеный, сам дописывает <*br/> теги.
 Убирать их постоянно как-то по костыльному)
Мне один и тот же код из минимальными изминениями нужно вставлять в разные записи. Думаю как упростить это все. Может в шорткод его запихнуть например? Посоветуйте элегантное решение :)

Comment: Если вставлять в текст. то именно  шорткод. Но вставлять в коннект один и тот же блок - само по себе плохое решение. А ифрейм - вообще ужас.

Comment: Так хорошо, а что с ифреймом не так? Какой еще вариант вставить шаблон в запись чтобы видно было работающие js файлы и другие css файы?

Comment: Ифрейм - зло в принципе. А юзать внутренний - вообще сюр какой-то. А для "другие варианты" надо задавать отдельный вопрос. С точным описанием задачи - что, куда. зачем.

Answer (score 0):

*public_html/wp-content/themes/YouThemeName/single.php*

**add you code...**